# MongoDB $geonear and $group by object property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this collection with many documents:

```
{
 "type"      : "Feature",
 "geometry"  : {
  "type"        : "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    19.038526,
    39.409768
  ]
},
 "properties": {
  "title"    : "xxx",
  "address"  : "xxx",
  "areaMajor": "Area 1",
  "areaSub1" : "xxx",
  "areaSub2" : "xxx",
  "email"    : "xxx",
  "tel1"     : "xxx",
  "tel2"     : "xxx",
  "fax"      : "xxx",
  "hours"    : "xxx",
  "site"     : "xxx",
  "facebook" : "xxx"
 }
},
{
 "type"      : "Feature",
 "geometry"  : {
  "type"        : "Point",
  "coordinates": [
    18.038526,
    35.409768
  ]
},
 "properties": {
  "title"    : "xxx",
  "address"  : "xxx",
  "areaMajor": "Area 2",
  "areaSub1" : "xxx",
  "areaSub2" : "xxx",
  "email"    : "xxx",
  "tel1"     : "xxx",
  "tel2"     : "xxx",
  "fax"      : "xxx",
  "hours"    : "xxx",
  "site"     : "xxx",
  "facebook" : "xxx"
 }
}
...
```

Then i use this aggregation to find near places and then group them by `properties.areaMajor` and count how many locations are inside this `areaMajor`.

```
 Area.aggregate(
        ([
            { "$geoNear": {
                    "near": {type: 'Point', coordinates:[24.038526,38.409768]} ,
                    "spherical": true,
                    "distanceField": "distance",
                    "distanceMultiplier": 6371
                }},
            {'$group': {
               _id: {
                     areaMajor: '$properties.areaMajor', 
                     areaSub1: '$properties.areaSub1', 
                     distance: '$distance'
                },
               count: {$sum: 1}}
            },
            { "$sort": { "distance": -1} },
         ])
    ).exec((err, area) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return res.status(500).json({
                title: 'error',
                error: {message: 'error message'}
            });
        }
            if (!area) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    title: 'error',
                    error: {message: 'error message'}
                });
            }
        res.status(200).json(area);
    });
```

**The output returns many duplicates, how can i group properly?**

Current output:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 1",
        "areaSub1": "xxxx",
        "distance": 1805205937.2356606
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 1",
        "areaSub1": "xxxx",
        "distance": 1804386562.3484473
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 2",
        "areaSub1": "xxxx",
        "distance": 104486562.3455322
    },
    "count": 1
},
{
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 2",
        "areaSub1": "xxxx",
        "distance": 203486562.3556778
    },
    "count": 1
}
```

expected output:

```
 {
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 1",
        "distance": 313110.6166765188
    },
    "count": 50
},
{
    "_id": {
        "areaMajor": "Area 2",
        "distance": 304502.5085277966
    },
    "count": 20
}
```

Comment: Your expected result already looks like what your query returns. Could you precise a bit what you get currently and how it's different from what you would like?

Comment: I've updated the question with current output.

Comment: I still don't see how the expected result and the result you get are linked.  If we get rid of subareas and group, then nothing's grouped since distances are not the same..

Comment: So distance is breaking grouping since it's never the same. How can i group first with `areaMajor` and then add the first `distance` found to the output under every `areaMajor`?